# Cannot share session with subdomains with Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, laravel, subdomain

I'm trying to use Laravel on a host which has many subdomains. Only one subdoman will have a Laravel's app running on but I'd like to share some things (like the current user) via PHP native session.

I've edited Laravel's session config to work with subdomains, changing the domain value:

```
'cookie' => 'mydomain_session',
'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
```

In another subdomain, where Laravel is not running, I'm trying to access the session in this way:

```
session_name("mydomain_session");
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.mydomain.com',false,true);
session_start();
```

but it's not working, if I try to echo the $_SESSION variable is empty.

The strangest thing is that if I try to echo the session_id() it's the same in both the subdomains.

Moreover if I set up the same script in a third subdomain it share the session with the other non-laravel subdomain with no problem.

So what I'm doing wrong? I'm missing something or Laravel is not managing the native PHP session in ordinary way?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does Laravel's `session::get()` is shared across the main domain and sub domain?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the vanilla $_SESSION array.

Comment: i dont think you can pass down sessions accross domains.. havent verified yet though

Comment: Between subdomains you can, as I said the session is shared between two subdomains where laravel is not running in, and also is working with two subdomains with laravel, it just seems that laravel's sessions is not compatible with the vanilla PHP's one.

Answer (score 0):

*or Laravel is not managing the native PHP session in ordinary way?*

Correct.

Throw this into the top of your routes.php file:

```
Session::put('foo', 'bar');
die(print_r($_SESSION));
```

You'll see that Laravel puts sessions into a multidimensional array.

For me, the "foo" session is contained in `$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably switch to JWT (Json Web tokens). Because of their design they do not suffer from this problem.

Probaly check this article for more info:
https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

You can share session across multiple sub domains in laravel by setting

```
config(session.domain, '.example.com');
```

OR 
in .env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN='.example.com'
```